# how to consume non-persistent MBO from maximo anywhere

Tags: maximo-anywhere

How can we consume non-persistent MBO from maximo anywhere app. I have a requirement to add/remove non-persistent mbo. I have done persistent mbo , is it same approach here also or different.Please share sample also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to consume Non-Persistent MBOs through the OSLC layer, depending on your Maximo level (this was added in relatively recent versions of Maximo).

However for non-persistent attributes and objects, you have to explicitly "Include" them in the Include/Exclude fields dialog inside the Object structures application.

Make sure that you can export or import these Non-persistent fields through the OSLC layer directly before attempting to use them in Maximo Anywhere.  Maximo Anywhere will consider them to be server-side/persistent attributes, and will not be aware that under the covers, the Maximo OSLC layer has implemented them as non-persistent attributes.

Comment: Please confirm maximo anywhere 7.6 version can consume Non-persistent MBO.

Comment: I also checked in Object Structure, its included. I am able to inspect request and response of non-persistent MBO from chrome browser after running maximo anywhere app. But since its non-persistent not able to see any response data. But data is not getting updated in server.Please advise if any configuration is missing.

Comment: i got Non-persistent MBO save sucess with json response which is having anyhwererefid. How can i verify if new record is inserted in server?